# Save Dictionary in application settings

Tags: c#, application-settings

I would like to do something like this :

app.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <appSettings>
   <setting1> 
  <add key ="key1" value ="value1"/>
  <add key ="key2" value ="value2"/>
</setting1>
<setting2>
  <add key ="key1" value ="value1"/>
  <add key ="key2" value ="value2"/>
</setting2>
```

my.cs:

```
Configuration config =
                    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var appSettings = config.AppSettings;

Assert.equals(appSettings.Settings["setting1"]["key1"] == "value1");
Assert.equals(appSettings.Settings["setting1"]["key2"] == "value2");
Assert.equals(appSettings.Settings["setting2"]["key1"] == "value1");
Assert.equals(appSettings.Settings["setting2"]["key2"] == "value2");
```

could I in any way receive similar behavior?

Thank You !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own configuration section - there are [many](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37776/Writing-a-complex-custom-configuration-section) [tutorials](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CustomConfigurationSectio.aspx) around.

Comment: And I wouldn't need to parse the xml of app.config in c# code?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest answer, don't and use a dot to "add a namespace" to the key:

```
<add key="setting1.key1" value="value1" />
<add key="setting1.key2" value="value2" />
<add key="setting2.key1" value="value3" />
<add key="setting2.key2" value="value4" />
```

You can then turn that into a nested dictionary in your code without too much effort, if you really need it like that.

Comment: Why - just do it once.  And the code is small and simple leading to less maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

Found built in solution using `System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler` [Under this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670669/how-do-you-use-sections-in-c-4-0-app-config) Thank you all!