# Get Section Names Programmatically from App.config C#

Tags: c#, configuration, config, app-config

Is there a way to programmatically get the section names by doing a loop instead of hard coding the names yourself?

For instance:

```xml
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="Test1"  type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
    <section name="Test2" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
  </configSections>
```

Hardcoding:

```
var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Test1") as NameValueCollection;
var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Test2") as NameValueCollection;
```

I do not want to hard code the Test1 and Test2 section names in the code.

Comment: Is this of help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670669/how-do-you-use-sections-in-c-sharp-4-0-app-config

Comment: so I have to use a sectionGroup and assign a specific sectionGroup name to do it? is there a way to avoid any hard coding of the names?

Comment: You don't need to use a section group - but the sections are included with all sections used in the application - so finding the ones specific to you would be more difficult. Using a sectionGroup you only get the sections you created but you may have to hard code that, or at least give it some easily identifiable name (application name as prefix ?? - could do that with section namesif you don't group them) I haven't used the ConfigurationManager enough to know if there are any easier ways. (If you are looking in the debugger the names are in the Keys section).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the section group names like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string configPath = @"..\..\App.config";
        var map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
        map.ExeConfigFilename = configPath;
        var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        for (int i = 0; i < config.SectionGroups.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(config.SectionGroups[i].SectionGroupName);
        }
    }
```